# Migrations dando erro 42000

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Estou tentando rodar minhas *migrations* (php artisan migrate) dentro do meu *container Docker*. Estou utilizando Lumen para desenvolver minha *API*. Não sei o que pode estar ocorrendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode estar acontecendo ? Refiz minhas migrations e nada mudou.

Comment: Parece que o nome ta tabela está em branco.

Answer (score 1):

Você não está setando o nome de sua tabela em suas migrations, veja que o modelo segundo a doc do laravel.

Ex:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

Uma dica é que ao criar a sua migration, utilize `--create=nome_da_tabela` ele criará a estrutura básica para você.